# Most efficient way to calculate ocurrences of a character in a string?

Tags: python, string, performance

I know there are various ways to calculate the instances of a character in a string, such as using `count()`, `collections.Counter`, regex, etc., but which way would be most efficient if I only wanted to find the instances of one specific character in a string?

Comment: "efficient" related to what? Execution time? Memory consumption? Lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Count is prolly the fastest and the most simple version tbh. You should stick to that :)